# how to get "mutual likes" using fql in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Hi
I am trying to get the likes that are shared between two friends and I am using this query:

```
SELECT source_id, target_id FROM connection
WHERE source_id = me()
AND source_id IN
   (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =me())
AND target_type = 'page'
```

which is supposed to get the pages that a user and his friends like, however I am getting an empty array in the results. What is wrong with the query?

Comment: Can you post the solution? It might be helpful for somebody. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Long time for this olution but i'm using:

SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=" + User.getCurrentUser().getFacebookId() + " AND object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id=" + u.getFacebookId() +")";